# Problem with Neo4j Graph Data Science Configuration

Tags: plugins, neo4j, config

I'm running Neo4j 5.6 Enterprise locally. I have APOC v5.6 and GDS v 2.3.5 installed. I also have a custom PlugIn installed.  I have an apoc.config file.

My custom PlugIn is working fine with no reference to allow or whitelist it in the neo4j.config file.  However, gds fails with this error message in the log
gds.graph.drop is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.

If I add  to the config
`dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=gds.* dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=gds.*`

and restart the database, then my custom PlugIn does not work.  If I also add a reference to allow it then neither it nor gds works.

There is an apparent bug here? I found nothing about a separate gds.config file, analogous to the new requirement for a separate apoc.config.
am I missing something here?

Comment: perhaps some conflicting dependencies?